# How to obtain argument names for a class in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a class with a `self` attribute which is a list of all arguments contained in `__init__`.

For example:

```
class thing:
    def __init__(self,x,y=None,fav_animal=None):
        
        self.x = x
        
        if y is None:
            self.y = None
        else:
            self.y = y
            
        if y is None:
            self.fav_animal = None
        else:
            self.fav_animal = fav_animal
            
        self.arg_list = 'some code here?'

    def args(self):
        print(self.arg_list)
```

I'm trying to come up with a solution whereby the function `args(self)` will return a list of the attribute *names*, ie `[x, y, fav_animal]` automatically. I can just set `self.arg_list = [x, y, fav_animal]` manually, but I'd like it to happen automatically whenever `__init__` is called.

If I do it through list appending, eg:

```
class thing:
    def __init__(self,x,y=None,fav_animal=None):
        arg_list = []
        self.x = x
        arg_list.append(self.x)
# etc...
        self.arg_list = arg_list
```

The function will return the *values* given to the arguments, rather than the names, as desired.

For context, the reason I want to do this is because I'll be using this type of thing in multiple projects, and I want to be able to add arguments to the `__init__` without having to update the list manually.

Many thanks!

Comment: `return list(vars(self).keys())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access everything definied in `__init__` using `__dict__`.

So your `args` method would be something like

```
    def args(self):
        print(list(self.__dict__.keys()))
```

which prints

```
['x', 'y', 'fav_animal']
```

or, as @Klaus pointed out

```
    def args(self):
        print(list(vars(self).keys()))
```

Comment: As for every double underscore function and attribute there's a method to use instead of accessing it directly. For `__dict__` it is `vars()`.

Comment: I agree, it should be preferred. Thanks.